# Jquery Slider Function is not working or showing in browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Jquery slider function is not working in browser and showing error. Please guide me how to fix this issue.I tried looking for this on StackOverflow and found lots of answers, but could not find success. Thanks

Following is the code for that

```js
$("#sliderHeight, #sliderWidth").slider({
  min: 100,
  max: 500,
  slide: refreshImage
});

$('#divOpacity').slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  value: 100,
  slide: refreshImage
});

function refreshImage() {
  var height = $('sliderHeight').slider('value');
  var width = $('sliderWidth').slider('value');
  var opacity = $('divOpacity').slider('value');

  $('#myImg').css({
    'height': height,
    'width': width,
    'opacity': opacity / 100
  });

  $('#divDimensions').html(
    'height = ' + height + '<br>' +
    'width = ' + width + '<br>' +
    'opacity = ' + opacity / 100 + '<br>'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<div id="sliderHeight"></div>
<br />
<div id="sliderWidth"></div>
<br />
<div id="divOpacity"></div>
<br />
<div id="divDimensions"></div>
<br />
<img id="myImg" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/29/18/20/chrysanthemum-202483_960_720.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
```

Comment: You included jquery, but did you include jquery-ui?

Comment: `not working in browser and showing error` - maybe include the error detail here?

Comment: It says slider () is not a function

Comment: Then you haven't included the jquery-ui js (and likely .css).  Or your code runs before your include.